# Обращение к родителю через потомка

Tags: css

Всем привет

такой вопрос

можно ли обратиться к родителю от потомка?

к примеру айдишник обернут в класс, можно ли через айдишник обратиться к родителю?

```
<div class="controls"> <div id="desc"></div</div>
```

типа обратного наследования

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: нельзя, выбирать можно только дочерние элементы или на одном уровне

Comment: с помощью js/jquery только